# UWP ListView, different item template for first and last item

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, datatemplateselector

Im trying to build DataTemplateSelector to choose different item template for my ListView first and last item.

In my DataTemplateSelector I try to find parent ListView and based on that check item index and choose correct data template.

The problem is that im unable to get parent ListView as in the SelectTemplateCore() DependencyObject container object's parent is null.

How should I choose different template based on item position?

**My DataTemplateSelector:**

```
public class FirstLastDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FirstItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LastItemTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var lv = GetListView(container);
        if (lv != null)
        {
            var i = lv.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return FirstItemTemplate;
            }
            else if (i == lv.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                return LastItemTemplate;
            }
        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }

    public static ListView GetListView(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element is ListView)
        {
            return (ListView)element;
        }
        var r = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);

            var result = GetListView(child);
            if (result == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ListView in xaml:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FirstLastDataTemplateSelector}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
```

Comment: Could you change the type of the first and last items (use an inheritor or wrapper)? You would have a much simpler task then.

Comment: I could change the type of the list items, but in this case I somehow do not want to touch the actual list item objects (if possible). I have used this kind template selector solution in WP8 (silverlight) app but now im unable to get the parent listview.

Comment: Have you tried checking the list with xamlspy? It should show you how it's built, and you could adjust the code according to that. Maybe there's a different ItemsControl somewhere in there that you need to check for it, and not the ListVIew. Listviews can be displayed in wildly different ways depending on the source. Grouping especially causes this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that im doing this completely wrong way. Im trying to find child (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()) when I actually need parent....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem in my original DataTemplateSelector. I was trying to find child object although I actually need the parent ListView.

**Here is updated, fixed, DataTemplateSelector:**

```
public class FirstLastDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FirstItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate LastItemTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var lv = GetListView(container);
        if (lv != null)
        {
            var i = lv.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return FirstItemTemplate;
            }
            else if (i == lv.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                return LastItemTemplate;
            }
        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }


    public static ListView GetListView(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var parentListView = parent as ListView;
        return parentListView ?? GetListView(parent);
    }
}
```